# Finding middle of single linked list

Tags: list, linked-list

I had modified my function to take care of the case for even number of nodes, but because of that my code does not work for an odd number of nodes. What is wrong?

```
public LinkedList findMiddleNode() {
    Node t1 = this.getHeadNode();
    Node t2 = this.getHeadNode();
    LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
    boolean even = false;
    while(t1.getNext() != null) {
        t1 = t1.getNext();
        if(t1.getNext()!= null && t1.getNext().getNext() != null) {
            t1 = t1.getNext();
            t2 = t2.getNext();              
        }
    }
    if(t1.getNext()!=null) 
        l.insertFirst(t2.getElement());
    else {
        l.insertFirst(t2.getElement());
        l.insertLast(t2.getNext().getElement());
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from question what is your expectation?

Comment: im trying to find middle node of linked list but my code is not working for case of odd number of nodes

Answer (score 1):

@oldrinb: thnx for ur help, here is my updated code:

```
public LinkedList findMiddleNode() {
    Node t1 = this.getHeadNode();
    Node t2 = this.getHeadNode();
    LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
    boolean even = false;
    while(t1.getNext() != null && t1.getNext().getNext() != null) {
            t1 = t1.getNext().getNext();
            t2 = t2.getNext();              
    }
    if(t1.getNext()==null) 
        l.insertFirst(t2.getElement());
    else {
        l.insertFirst(t2.getElement());
        l.insertLast(t2.getNext().getElement());
    }
    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* determine length of list */
int n = 0;
for (Node cur = getHeadNode(); cur != null; cur = cur.getNext()) {
  ++n;
}

/* go half-way */
int m = n / 2;
Node mid = getHeadNode();
while (m > 0) {
  mid = mid.getNext();
  --m;
}

/* if n is odd, both mid and mid.getNext() are the middle */
if ((n % 2) != 0) {
  Node mid2 = mid.getNext();
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

... or, alternatively,

```
Node tortoise = getHeadNode();
Node hare = getHeadNode();

do {
  tortoise = tortoise.getNext();
} while (hare.getNext() != null && (hare = hare.getNext().getNext()) != null);

/* tortoise is the middle */
```

Comment: i want to implement this without using a counter

Comment: @ueg1990 implement a variant of Floyd's tortoise-and-hare algorithm.